# How to open a publicly accessible port?

Tags: server, port, hosting, firewall, windows-firewall

I run a server (Photon) on my pc and it uses port 9090.

I can access it with the local IP address, with the IP address of the internal router network but not the public one. Even through this public IP address pings perfectly.

To run the server publicly I DON'T use a router but direct connection. All possible firewalls are disabled, no antivirus, all ports in Inbound Rules are opened (just in case). But still `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 9090` gives me `Could not open connection to the host, on port 9090: Connect failed`.

If I enter `netstat -aonb` into the cmd I see that

TCP    0.0.0.0:9090                    LISTENING

What means that it must be listened for any IP address (0.0.0.0) on port 9090, as I understand

But port 9090 is still closed, as online services say. And if I try to connect to the server from the client (as it works for internal network) I get `Error: 1004 Master peer error timeout`

What else can I do to open this port and to finally get it accessible via public network?

I use Windows.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the problem seems inconsistent.  Most likely, the claims that "All possible firewalls are disabled [... and] all ports in Inbound Rules are opened" are one or both incorrect or misleading.

If

- the test client can successfully ping the destination machine, and
- `netstat` shows that a client is listening to 0.0.0.0:9090 / TCP on the destination machine, but
- the test client cannot connect to port 9090 at the same address, and
- test clients can successfully connect to port 9090 on the destination machine via others of its addresses, both before and after

then by far the most likely scenario is that the failing connection attempts are being blocked by a firewall.  Even if no firewall at all is running on the server itself, there may be one running on a router on the network path between client and server.  Note that router firewalls often distinguish between internal traffic and external, applying stricter controls to the latter.  Some have entirely separate rule sets for the two.